# How to pass a variable to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I pass the id to the function in the following javascript code?

```
for(var i = 1; i<=10; i++){     
    var id = i;
        $("#result-" + id).click(function(event){
        makeFeatureSelected(id, true);
    });
}
```

In this way, the value of id is always 11.

Thanks.

Comment: see more about [closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elegant solution could be:

```
var makeFeatureSelected = function(id, val) {
  console.log(id);
}

$('[id^="result-"]').on('click', function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    makeFeatureSelected(id, true);
});
```

**Explanation**

- $('[id^="result-"]') JQuery's selector: select all element that have an id that starts with string "result-"
- $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]: split id string of element clicked and take the second value, in your case the id;

**Plus**
If you want to do something only with 10 first id, you can add an if block to check id.

Comment: This solution works and it is flexible as there can be less than 10 results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd just be as easy as passing ID as a parameter to your function.

```
for(var i = 1; i<=10; i++){     
    var id = i;
        $("#result-" + id).click(function(event, id){
        makeFeatureSelected(id, true);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just extract it from the ID?

```
for(var i = 1; i<=10; i++){     

        $("#result-" + id).click(function(event){
        var id = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/)[0];
        makeFeatureSelected(id, true);
    });
}
```

that way you could skip the for loop and just assign a class to all result elements. A little tidier perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet id is always 11 because of the closure formed when you define a function within a loop.
This is a common mistake in javascript.

The way around this is by making further use of closures.

```
function makeSelectedCallback(id){
    return function(){
        makeFeatureSelected(id, true);
    }
}

function yourExistingLoopLogic(){
    for(var i = 1; i<=10; i++){     
        var id = i;
        $("#result-" + id).click(function(event){
            makeSelectedCallback(id, true);
        });
    }
}
```

Have a read of the [Mozilla closure guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake) it covers closures in detail